# Am I comparing enum values with C++'s "or" operator correctly?

Tags: c++, enums

I have written a piece of code that doesn't seem to work as required:

```
typedef enum{none=0,apple,grape,orange} FRUIT;

FRUIT first = rand()%4;
FRUIT second = rand()%4;
FRUIT third = rand()%4;
```

So in my if condition, can I have

```
if (first == (none | apple | grape | orange) &&
    second == apple &&
    third == (none | apple | grape | orange)
{
    cout<<"Here"<<<endl;
}
```

The variables `first` and `third` can have any of the *apple*, *grape*, *none* or *orange* values. So is the if condition correct? I am not getting the desired output as it's not entering the if condition at all.

Comment: `a == (b | c)` is NOT the same as `(a == b) || (a == c)`, which is what you probably wanted. There are probably a few hundred questions on this on here ;) .

Comment: [Don't use `rand`. It sucks.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) And especially don't use modulus.

Comment: @chris Sure, it's a good idea to learn about good random numbers early, but really, for picking fruit it doesn't matter that much...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  basic Boolean logic.


Comment: @MitchWheat I'm not sure I agree. I think basic Boolean logic is an okay topic for StackOverflow, and as far as I know, we don't have a close vote category for "too basic" yet.

Comment: is basic addition on-topic. No. The most basic requirement to be able to program is basic Boolean logic.

Comment: @us2012, Always good to know better *before* you go write lottery software.

Comment: Why `% 4`? Why not just `& 3`? It's much faster.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: If there's any significant difference in speed between `x % 4` and `x & 3`, you need a better compiler. Clarity first.

Comment: @Keith not if you're in Debug mode.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: `gcc -g` generates `andl $3, %eax` for both. In any case, if you're in Debug mode, why should you care about microscopic differences in performance?

Comment: @Keith well, that's gcc. Must be preference now a days. It makes me think it's faster, so I code that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In condition:

```
first == (none | apple | grape | orange)
```

you should use logical or (`||`) instead of bitwise or (`|`). Unfortunately even if you changed it to:

```
first == (none || apple || grape || orange)
```

the right side of this condition would be evaluated first making it (in this case) equivalent to:

```
first == true
```

which is still semantically different from what you probably meant:

```
first == none || first == apple || first == grape || first == orange
```

Also note that using `rand()` isn't very wise here. You can try to use `std::random_shuffle` instead:

```
FRUIT fruit[] = { none, apple, grape, orange,
                  none, apple, grape, orange,
                  none, apple, grape, orange};
srand(time(NULL));
std::random_shuffle(&fruit[0], &fruit[11]);
FRUIT first = fruit[0];
FRUIT second = fruit[1];
FRUIT third = fruit[2];
```

just don't forget to `#include <algorithm>` :)

Comment: Using || instead of | has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @EJP: If using `rand()` is what you meant, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Try reading what I actually wrote. I didn't mention rand(). I don't see anything unclear about what I did write. The first six lines of your answer are completely irrelevant, i.e. everything before 'you probably meant'. The part you have for some reason added about rand() is also irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP: In case you meant missing `)`, that one was just a typo while asking a question, since OP complained about the incorrect output, not problems during compilation.

Comment: Stop it. Stop jumping to conclusions. Stop now. Just read what I  wrote. I didn't say anything about rand(); I didn't say anything about missing parentheses either. If I had wanted to, I would have done so. What I did write seems perfectly clear to me. Your thought processes baffle me. You have written precisely one and a half lines that answer the question: everything else, including all these bizarre comments, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I comparing enum values with C++'s “or” operator correctly?

No. You need to write:

```
first == none || first == apple || first == grape || first == orange
```